Can this theory interpret TG? Would its Reinhardt's extension be equivalent to the usual one?
Language: FOL
Primitives: $=, \in$
Axioms:
Extensionality: as in Z
Define: $\operatorname {set}(y) \iff \exists x: y \in x$
Comprehension: $$n=0,1,2, \ldots \\ \forall \operatorname {set} x_1, \cdots, \forall \operatorname {set} x_n \, \exists X \forall  y \, (y \in X \leftrightarrow \operatorname {set} (y) \land \ \phi^{\operatorname {set}})$$
Where $\phi^{\operatorname {set}}$ is the bounded by "$\operatorname {set}$" form of formula $\phi$. Of course, $X$ doesn't occur in $\phi$.
Define: $x=V \iff \forall y \, (y \subseteq x)$
Define $V_\alpha $ to copy the usual intention$^\dagger$, for each ordinal class $\alpha$
Ranks: $\forall x  \exists \alpha: x \subseteq V_\alpha$
Definitions:

$\operatorname {wacc} \lambda \iff \forall \alpha < \lambda \, \exists \beta: \alpha < \beta \leq \lambda \land \operatorname {acc} \beta$
$\operatorname {acc} \beta \iff \exists c \subset \beta: |c| < \beta \land (\bigcup c= |\beta| \lor  \beta \leq | \mathcal P(c)|)$

$\operatorname {wacc}$ stands for weakly-accessible ordinal.
Hierarchy: $\operatorname {wacc} \alpha \to V_\alpha \in V$
Choice: as in Z.


Would $V \models \sf TG$?
If we remove choice and add Rheinhardt's axiom of existence of a non-trivial elementary embedding from $V$ to $V$. Would that be equivalent to the usual addition of it over axioms of $\sf MK$?


Where $\sf TG$ is Tarski-Grothendieck set theory.

$^\dagger$: The intention is to have: $V_\alpha = \bigcup \{\mathcal P (V_\beta) \mid \beta < \alpha \}$, this is captured as: $$V_\alpha= x \iff  \exists f : \operatorname {dom}(f)= \alpha ; \beta \mapsto \mathcal P (\bigcup \{ f(\lambda) \mid \lambda < \beta \}) \land x= \bigcup \operatorname {rng}(f)$$; where function, domain, and range are defined in the usual manner, the underlying ordered pair implementation is Kuratowski's.
